# javascript questionare with checkboxes divided in many pages

Tags: javascript

I am making a questionnaire in javascript with checkboxes.
The total number of checkboxes are more than 50 so I will display them on 5 pages (5 pages with 10 checkboxes each)

What I need is: A nice page slide without refreshing.

Example: The user will get a questionare with 10 checboxes and after selecting them, he will be diverted to another page with more checkboxes to select.

Comment: Good luck! Shall I tell you what I need? (A Java API for the raspberry pi camera) [ask]

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Test
        </title>
        <style type='text/css'>
            div.visible { display:block; }
            div.hidden { display:none; }
        </style>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function NextDiv (newDivID) {
                var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
                for (var i in divs) {
                    divs[i].className = 'hidden';
                }
                document.getElementById(newDivID).className = 'visible';
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body >
        <form method='post' action='' onsubmit='alert ("Where to send this data?"); return false;'>
            <div id='div1' class='visible'>
                <h2> page 1</h2>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='button' onclick='NextDiv("div2");' value='next'>
            </div>
            <div id='div2' class='hidden'>
                <h2> page 2</h2>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='button' onclick='NextDiv("div3");' value='next'>
            </div>
            <div id='div3' class='hidden'>
                <h2> page 3</h2>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='button' onclick='NextDiv("div4");' value='next'>
            </div>
            <div id='div4' class='hidden'>
                <h2> page 4</h2>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='button' onclick='NextDiv("div5");' value='next'>
            </div>
            <div id='div5' class='hidden'>
                <h2> page 5</h2>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
                <input type='submit'>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```